# Comparison between objects matchs, but not between arrays of objects

Tags: python-3.x, object, hash, compare

So the issue i have is while comparing objects from the Class `House`, one against each other.

```
    def __init__(self, door: str, address: str, rooms: List[room],
                 garaje=None, number=None):
        self.door = door
        self.address = address
        # ensure and deserialize if needed the list of rooms
        try:
            if all(isinstance(room, dict) for room in rooms):
                rooms = list(map(room.from_json, rooms))
                # deserialize rooms
            assert all(isinstance(room, Room) for room in rooms)
        except AssertionError as e:
            logger.error("Rooms incorrect")
            raise e
        self.rooms = rooms
        self.garaje = garaje
        self.number = number

    def __eq__(self, other):
        '''
        Two houses instances will be equal when at least following values match:
         door,
         address
         rooms
        '''
        if not isinstance(other, House):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.door == other.door and
                self.address == other.address and
                self.rooms == other.rooms)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.door, self.address, self.rooms))


    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, data):
        return cls(**data)
```

The class `House` contains a list of room objects based on the Room Class:

```
class Room():

    def __init__(self, name: str, description: str, windows: list = None, bahtroom: bool = True,
                 , room_id: int = None, house_number: int = None):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.windows = windows
        self.bathroom = bathroom
        self.room_id = room_id
        self.house_number = house_number

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Two room instances will be equal when at least following values match
         name,
         description,
         windows,
         bathroom
        """

        if not isinstance(other, Room):
            return NotImplemented

        return (self.name == other.name and
                self.description == other.description and
                self.windows == other.windows and
                self.bathroom == other.bathroom 
                )

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name, self.descritpion, self.windows, self.bathroom))

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, data):
        return cls(**data)
```

When comparing houses result is they are not equal due to a difference in the Rooms list.
Rooms are different when comparing them in the list:

self 27 rooms

```
[<housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f83c8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8710>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8550>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8978>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8048>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8a20>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8518>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8898>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f87b8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f84a8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8278>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8c50>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8940>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f86a0>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8320>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8c18>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8a58>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f80b8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8828>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8b70>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f85f8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f81d0>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8358>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8240>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8128>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8400>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f8668>]
```

other 27 rooms

```
[<housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1470>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1978>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1f98>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1d68>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1a58>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1cf8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f11d0>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1438>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1898>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1ef0>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f10f0>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1198>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1240>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f18d0>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f17f0>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f15c0>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1828>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1518>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f13c8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1f28>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1160>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1860>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f12e8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f17b8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1ba8>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f1400>, <housing.classes.Room object at 0x7f465f6f14a8>]
```

But when comparing comparing Rooms in each Rooms list I keep getting that all rooms in `self` are present in `other`.

As work around I added in the `House` class  inside `__eq__` a nasty check, that looks like this:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        '''
        Two houses instances will be equal when at least following values match:
         door,
         address
         rooms
        '''
        if not isinstance(other, House):
            return NotImplemented
        rooms_from_other = True
        rooms_from_self = True
        for room in self.rooms:
            if room not in other.rooms:
                rooms_from_self = False
                break
        for room in other.rooms:
            if room not in self.rooms:
                rooms_from_other = False
                break
        return (self.door == other.door and
                self.address == other.address and
                rooms_from_other and rooms_from_self)
```

What is the good way to do this, and why my room objects are equal when compared directly but not in the list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the 2 list of rooms are not ordered the same way? (You code does not show how you build them).

You could first sort the 2 list and them compare the sorted lists.

```
return (self.door == other.door and
        self.address == other.address and
        sorted(self.rooms) == sorted(other.rooms))
```

Comment: And that was it, simple and neat and i was not seeing it.

Comment: After some further checks I realized that for this to work (sort) I have to implement `__lt__` inside my room instance.